# Sync a class variable with multiple threads

Tags: python, multithreading, synchronization, python-decorators, class-variables

I'm trying to create a decorator that will globally validate if the request bucket is full or not.
The bucket size is 40, the leak rate is 2 per second.
I want to be able to thread multiple instances of different requests while maintaining the bucker sub 40. How is it possible that the self.bucket_current goes negative? Also, how do I debug these threads and what they do?

```py
from time import sleep
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from math import ceil

class Counter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bucket_size = 40
        self.bucket_current = 0
        self.bucket_leak_rate = 2


    def countdown(self, secs):
        self.bucket_current += secs
        print(self.bucket_current)
        r = ceil(self.bucket_current/self.bucket_leak_rate)
        sleep(1)
        while self.bucket_current > 0:
            for _ in range(1, r+1):
                if self.bucket_current != 1:
                    self.bucket_current -= 2
                else:
                    self.bucket_current -= 1

                print(self.bucket_current)
                sleep(1)


c = Counter()

with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    executor.submit(c.countdown, 9)
    sleep(3)
    executor.submit(c.countdown, 7)
```

Output:

```
9
7
5
3
10
8
6
4
2
0
-2
-4
-6
-8
-10
-12
-14
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 1):

> How is it possible that the self.bucket_current goes negative?

The answer to this, is that according to your code, after your first line `executor.submit(c.countdown, 9)`, the thread executes alone, and after 3 seconds (`sleep(3)`) another thread joins the execution `executor.submit(c.countdown, 7)` and there isn't any syncronization between these 2 threads.

you need to provide a mechanism to synchronize these 2 threads, here's a simple decorator I use sometimes:

```
from time import sleep
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from math import ceil
from functools import wraps
from threading import Lock


def synchronized(tlockname):
    """A decorator to place an instance based lock around a method """

    def _synched(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def _synchronizer(self, *args, **kwargs):
            tlock = self.__getattribute__(tlockname)
            tlock.acquire()
            try:
                return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
            finally:
                tlock.release()

        return _synchronizer

    return _synched


class Counter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bucket_size = 40
        self.bucket_current = 0
        self.bucket_leak_rate = 2
        self.bucket_lock = Lock()

    @synchronized("bucket_lock")
    def countdown(self, secs):
        self.bucket_current += secs
        print(self.bucket_current)
        r = ceil(self.bucket_current / self.bucket_leak_rate)
        sleep(1)
        while self.bucket_current > 0:
            for _ in range(1, r + 1):
                if self.bucket_current != 1:
                    self.bucket_current -= 2
                else:
                    self.bucket_current -= 1

                print(self.bucket_current)
                sleep(1)


c = Counter()

with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    executor.submit(c.countdown, 9)
    sleep(3)
    executor.submit(c.countdown, 7)
```